# Разбивка списка по словам Python

Tags: python, split

Всем привет, пытаюсь разбить текст по словам, вместо этого получается по буквам:

```
with open("art.txt", encoding='utf-8') as f:  
    data_art = f.read()  
absx = []  

for i in data_art.split():
    absx.extend(i)

absx[:10]

>> Ф', 'о', 'м', 'а', 'Г', 'о', 'р', 'д', 'е', 'в'
```

Вариант с предварительным записыванием прочитанного в отдельный список также не работает.
Сорри за дамми-вопрос, понимаю, что упускаю что-то очень простое, но не понимаю, что.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import string

f = '../kek.txt'
l =[]

with open(f, encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for line in f:
        for i in line.split():
            l.append(i.strip(string.punctuation))

print(l[:10])
```

вроде работает

```
>> ['Mr', 'and', 'Mrs', 'Dursley', 'of', 'number', 'four', 'Privet', 'Drive', 'were']
```

Comment: сработало, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2):

В data_art содержится список строк. Поэтому сначала надо разделить текст  по строкам в цикле, а потом уже сплитить строки на слова.

split() уже разделяет по словам, дополнительный цикл не нужен.

```
for line in data_art:
    words = line.split()
    absx.extend(words)
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что без цикла получаю ошибку:



---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-822cd17f1dad> in <module>
----> 1 absx = data_art.split()
      
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Дополнил ответ.